# Add a fixed-width pseudo element before a full-width element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to add some text before each blockquote. Here's an illustration:

[image]

The caveat is that the html is generated from markdown, so it can't really be modified. It will always have the format 
`<blockquote> <div>content</div> </blockquote>`.

I've tried using flex grid, but I really don't know what I'm doing with flex. Here's as close as I've gotten:

```css
blockquote {
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: flex;
}
blockquote > *::before {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    content: "quote";
    flex: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
}
blockquote > * {
    flex: 100%;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <ol>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
    </ol>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <div> other content </div>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the pseudo element to be a child of the `blockquote`. Use [`writing-mode: vertical-lr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) to display the text vertically, and rotate the text to start from the bottom. See comments in the css.

```css
blockquote {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

 /** the pseudo element should be a child of blockquote **/
blockquote::before {
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em; /** align the text horizontally **/
  writing-mode: vertical-lr; /** set to vertical **/
  transform: rotate(180deg); /** rotate to start from the bottom **/
  text-align: center; /** align the text vertically **/
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  content: "Quote";
}

blockquote>* {
  flex: 1; /** take all remaining free space **/
  padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <ol>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
  </ol>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <div> other content </div>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to use a background image positioned on the left, however there are a few ways you an achieve this with CSS only.

You can do this without using flex box or rotating the pseudo element.

**Edit:** +1 to @G-Cyr for the use of `transform: scale(-1);`

```css
blockquote {
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    position: relative;
}
blockquote::before {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    content: "quote";
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-transform: scale(-1);
    transform: scale(-1);
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <ol>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
    </ol>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <div> other content </div>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at writing-mode and flex (I still add answer approach different from @itod )

```css
blockquote {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gray 1.5em, lightgray 1.5em) lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: ' quote';
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  color: white;
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 1.5em;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: scale(-1) translatex(1.9em)
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <ol>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
  </ol>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <div> other content </div>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
    <blockquote>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <ol>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
<li>blah</li>
<li>blah</li>

    </ol>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <div> other content </div>
</blockquote>
```

CSS

```
blockquote {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

blockquote::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  content: "Quote";
  width: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
}

blockquote>* {
    padding: 0 0 0 1.5rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nhz92mth